# Another C++ output alignment issue

Tags: c++, cout, text-align, iomanip, setw

I've been trying to align the following code for the last 3 hours with zero success. Could anybody fill me in about what I'm doing wrong?
My aim is to have the string literal left aligned and the variable right aligned like this:

```
Loan amount:             $ 10000.00
Monthly Interest Rate:        0.10%
```

But this is what I keep geting:

```
Loan amount:             $ 10000.00
Monthly Interest Rate:   0.10%
```

And this is the most recent version of what I've been trying:

```
cout << setw(25) << "Loan amount:" << right << "$ "<< amount << endl;
cout << setw(25) << "Monthly Interest Rate:"<< right<< rateMonthly << "%" << endl;
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: `right` has no effect unless used in conjunction with `setw`, e.g. `<< right <<  setw(10) << rateMonthly`.

Comment: As shown by the other answers (although not explained why), `right` is "sticky"; so you need to set `left` again for the next line . In fact all the manipulators are sticky except for `setw`.

Comment: If you're going to be getting into more complicated formatting that needs left-right justification, you might want to write your own function to do that, which takes the left string and the right string and the width as arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setw` field width is defined for the [next item to be output and is reset to 0 afterwards](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).  This is why only the text is displayed on 25 chars and not the remaining output on the line.

The [`right`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and `left` justifier define where the fill chars are to be put in the field.  This means that it applies only to the current field if it has a defined width.  This is why the justification is not applied to the items following the text.

Here you to obtain the [expected result](http://ideone.com/gdxoW6):

```
cout <<setw(25)<< left<< "Loan amount:" <<  "$ "<< setw(10)<<right << amount << endl;
cout <<setw(25)<< left << "Monthly Interest Rate:"<<"  "<<setw(10)<<right<< rateMonthly << " %" << endl;
```

If you want the $ to be next to the number, you have to make sure that the $ and the number are concatenated into a single object to output, either by puting them together in a single string, or by using monetary format.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Like I mentioned, I've been trying for a while and I tried specifying setw() and left-right twice for a line separately but I did not know that it only applies to the next item. I guess the $ and % signs messed up the output.
You learn something everyday I guess. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [live demo](http://ideone.com/rL7fMm), which should output exactly what you want. 
There's no way to set the precision with `std::to_string(double)`, that's why I've created a small helper to do it.

```
auto to_string_precision(double amount, int precision)
{
    stringstream stream;
    stream << fixed << setprecision(precision) << amount;
    return stream.str();
};

cout << setw(25) << left << "Loan amount:" << setw(10) << right << ("$ " + to_string_precision(amount, 2)) << endl;
cout << setw(25) << left << "Monthly Interest Rate:" << setw(10) << right << (to_string_precision(rateMonthly, 2) + "%") << endl;
```

Alternative, I still think this one looks better:

```
cout << setw(25) << left << "Loan amount:" << "$ " << amount << endl;
cout << setw(25) << left << "Monthly Interest Rate:" << rateMonthly << "%" << endl;
```

Comment: I think he is looking for the last digit of the amount to line up with the `%` on the next line

Answer (score -1):

If you want

```
Loan amount:             $ 10000.00
Monthly Interest Rate:        0.10%
```

If you don't want to bother with left and right you can use

```
cout  << "Loan amount:"  <<setw(25)<< "$ "<< amount << endl;
cout  << "Monthly Interest Rate:"<< setw(19)<< rateMonthly << "%" << endl;
```

You can use the following

```
cout << setw(25) << left << "Loan amount:"<< "$ " << amount << endl;
cout << setw(28) << left << "Monthly Interest Rate:" << rateMonthly << "%" <<endl;
```